# chess.js - unable to make a move using the permissive parser

Tags: javascript, chess

I can only make moves using the SAN and object notations. The permissive parser doesn't work. I tried using the `{ permissive: true }` option but it doesn't seem to do anything. Did I miss something?

```
const game = new Chess();
game.move('e2-e4');
game.fen();
```

Returns `rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1`.

```
const game = new Chess();
game.move('e4'); // Or game.move({ from: 'e2', to: 'e4' });
game.fen();
```

Returns `rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq e3 0 1`.
And by the way, 'e4' looks more permissive than 'e2-e4' to me...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. The first snippet makes the move when I try. How are you importing the chess.js module?

Comment: Like that : `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chess.js/0.10.2/chess.js"
        integrity="sha384-s3XgLpvmHyscVpijnseAmye819Ee3yaGa8NxstkJVyA6nuDFjt59u1QvuEl/mecz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: Ok, that explains it. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: In a browser context, add the `sloppy` option:

```
game.move('e2-e4', { sloppy: true })
```

## Why

At the time of writing, the latest version of chess.js is v0.13.4 and there is (still) a difference between the npm module and the browser version.

### Node.js

When using your code in Node.js, the first snippet performs the move:

```
import { Chess } from 'chess.js'

const game = new Chess();
game.move('e2-e4');
console.log(game.fen());
```

This has the expected, correct output:

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq - 0 1
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcomq768408415459839)

### Browser

In a browser, we can reproduce the issue when including this module script:

```html
<script type="module">
    import { Chess } from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chess.js/0.13.4/chess.min.js'
    
    const game = new Chess();
    console.log(game.move('e2-e4')); // null!
    console.log(game.fen());
</script>
```

## The Difference

The difference can be seen in the source code:

In the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/blob/master/src/chess.ts#L1317C1-L1317C1) we find this function definition (heading):

```
  move(
    move: string | { from: string; to: string; promotion?: string },
    { strict = false }: { strict?: boolean } = {}
  ) {
 {
    /*
     * The move function can be called with in the following parameters:
     *
     * .move('Nxb7')       <- argument is a case-sensitive SAN string
     *
     * .move({ from: 'h7', <- argument is a move object
     *         to :'h8',
     *         promotion: 'q' })
     *
     *
     * An optional strict argument may be supplied to tell chess.js to
     * strictly follow the SAN specification.
     */
```

But in the source code provided [by CNDjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/chess.js/0.13.4) (for browsers) we find:

```
move: function (move, options) {
      /* The move function can be called with in the following parameters:
       *
       * .move('Nxb7')      <- where 'move' is a case-sensitive SAN string
       *
       * .move({ from: 'h7', <- where the 'move' is a move object (additional
       *         to :'h8',      fields are ignored)
       *         promotion: 'q',
       *      })
       */

      // allow the user to specify the sloppy move parser to work around over
      // disambiguation bugs in Fritz and Chessbase
      var sloppy =
        typeof options !== 'undefined' && 'sloppy' in options
          ? options.sloppy
          : false
```

Note that the first one foresees a `strict` option, while the second provides a `sloppy` option. The default is the opposite.

The node.js module evolved over time, changing the default for this option from strict to sloppy, thereby replacing the `sloppy` option with the `strict` option. See some of the [stale branches](https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/branches) of the GitHub project which still have the previous behaviour.

## Solution

So in a browser context you should provide the `sloppy` option:

```html
<script type="module">
    import { Chess } from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chess.js/0.13.4/chess.min.js'
    
    const options = { sloppy: true };
    const game = new Chess();
    console.log(game.move('e2-e4', options));
    console.log(game.fen());
</script>
```